# Matching multiple letters and special characters in regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to catch strings around the acronym ADJ. The strings look like this:

```
·NOM·JJ·ADJ+CASE_DEF_GEN
·NOM·JJ·ADJ+CASE_DEF_ACC
·NOM·JJ·ADJ+CASE_INDEF_GEN
·NOM·DT+JJ·DET+ADJ+NSUFF_FEM_SG+CASE_DEF_GEN
·NOM·JJ·ADJ+CASE_INDEF_GEN
·NOM·JJ·ADJ+NSUFF_FEM_SG+CASE_INDEF_GEN
·NOM·DT+JJ·DET+ADJ+NSUFF_FEM_SG+CASE_DEF_ACC
```

So far I have this:
`/[A-Z·\+#_]*?[·\+]ADJ[·\+][A-Z_·\+#]*?/g`

But it only matches from the beginning of the strings until "ADJ+" `·NOM·DT+JJ·DET+ADJ+`.

Since the rest of the strings after ADJ have the same composition of the beginning of the strings before ADJ, I thought this `/[A-Z·\+#_]*?[·\+]/g` should work, but it doesn't.
How do I get it to match the rest of the string?

Comment: Usually (all the time), if you have a `*?` at the last part of your regex, the engine takes a dump and quits matching. In your case, you don't need anything but a `*`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want to make sure if you have an `ADJ` in the string, which if so, maybe we could simplify our expression to something similar to:

```
([A-Z·+#_]*)\bADJ\b([A-Z·+#_]*)
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT1FsF/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/dT1FsF/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Comment: Thank you so much especially for the explanation. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

That `*?` quantifier after the `+ADJ+` phrase is satisfied with the empty string right after it, since the `?` makes the quantifier before it match ["*the minimum number of times possible*"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers) and for `*` that is zero times.

So drop the `?`, which also has no purpose for the rest of the line

```
perl -wE'$_=q(-XADJX-JJ+ADJ-REST-); 
    ($before, $after) = /(.*?)[+\-]ADJ[+\-](.*)/; 
    say for $before,$after'
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `?` at the end would match the whole strings,

```
/[A-Z·\+#_]*?[·\+]ADJ[·\+][A-Z_·\+#]*/g
```

I am not entirely sure why you needed a `?` in a `*`.